# How to change direction of a text when it comes to certain symbols

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, markdown, laravel-9

I'm using Laravel 9 to build a forum just like Stackoverflow.

So I installed a markdown editor for adding and displaying code snippets and it works fine.

This is the code:

```
<p dir="rtl">
    @markdown
    {!! $question->que_body !!}
    @endmarkdown
</p>
```

And **`$question->que_body`** holds this data at the DB:

````
word placed into the right section


```

//First Table
        Schema::create('lkp_anime_lists', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            //more columns here
        });
//Second one
        Schema::create('lkp_cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('lkp_anime_list_id');
        });

        Schema::table('lkp_cards', function ($table) {
            $table->foreign('lkp_anime_list_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('lkp_anime_lists')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

```
````

As you can see for defining codes, I used **```` ``` ````** at the beginning and ending of the code.

Result:

[image]

The only problem with this is that, because I set `dir="rtl"` for all the texts (including the codes).

And this is wrong!

Because **the codes must be shown from left to right** and not right to left!

But I don't know how can I apply this scenario...

So if you know or if you have any idea about how this thing can be possible, please let me know...

Thanks!

Comment: Markdown is converted to HTML and code is (most likely) wrapped in a `<pre></pre>` block so you can use style `pre { direction: ltr; }` though how the code is generated depends on what you are using to get the `@markdown` directive

Answer (score 0):

```
   .code-block {
    direction: ltr;
    }
```

This will set the direction of the code block to left to right, and the code will be displayed as expected.

Alternatively, you can add the "dir" attribute to the code block instead of the parent "p" tag, like this:

````
<div dir="ltr">
```{.code-block}
// your code goes here
```
````